# How to order a Result by Alphabet in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I want to order my result by name in alphabetic order. I tested this:

```
select u.name from User as u 
order by u.name desc
```

This did not work. How can I sort alphabetically?

Comment: What do you mean "This did not work."?, what do you get when you test?

Comment: This is an sql error you want SELECT name From user order by name desc

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a Hibernate Query Language, try this:

```
from User u select u.name order by u.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a console:

```
User.executeQuery("Select u.name from User u order by u.name desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

This query is correct, there is nothing wrong in it:

select u.name from User as u order by u.name desc

But there is problem in this query:

from User u select u.name order by u.name

The syntax does not seems correct. 
For more queries you can see: [org hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)